# Do coordinates belong to a sphere? Prints wrong result if we print result after printing the coordinates. Blows my mind

Tags: python

-------------The task is to find if the points belong to a sphere. R = 2-----------------------

Inputs are:

```
0.0 1.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 1.1
0.0 1.0 1.5
```

----------------Code--------------------------------------------------------

```
abscissas = map(float, input().split())
ordinates = map(float, input().split())
applicates = map(float, input().split())
print(*abscissas)
print(*ordinates)
print(*applicates)
print(all(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2 <= 4 for x, y, z in zip(abscissas, ordnates, applicates)))
```

Prints:

```
0.0 1.0 2.0
0.0 0.0 1.1
0.0 1.0 1.5
True
```

--------Same code, but without printing the coordinates------------------------------

```
abscissas = map(float, input().split())
ordinates = map(float, input().split())
applicates = map(float, input().split())
print(all(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2 <= 4 for x, y, z in zip(abscissas, ordinates, applicates)))
```

Prints:

```
False
```

Comment: `map` is a consumable iterable. Does it behave as expected if you wrap each `map` with a `tuple` to prevent it being consumed?

Comment: When you print each individual `map` object, it cycles through them and uses them up, so to speak.

Comment: Right.  `all` given an empty iterator produces `True`.  Nice little gotcha.